# How to fix GPUImage2 framework causes error when removing it from the background apps?

Tags: swift, gpuimage, crash

I'm working around photo effects then I found **GPUImage2** framework is amazing easy and useful but there is a problem like when I add this framework to my project it started to crash. The app working without problem until removing or closing it from background. When I do it I'm receiving error message : `Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9`, then I just removed the framework from the project and problem is fixed!
So I don't know what I'm doing wrong?!

My way to adding framework like this :

1. Right click on the project in left navigator and choosing "Add files.."
2. Go to Build Phases -> Add it to "Target dependencies" + "Link binary with libraries".
3. Build the project
4. Add "import GPUImage.." to view controller.

**MacOS Version** : High Sierra 10.13.6 
**XCode Version** : 9.4.1 (9F2000) 
**Swift Version** : 4.1 
**Simulator** : iPhone 8 Plus with OS 11.4 (15F79)

Can someone help me about this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quitting app causes error "Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42331852/quitting-app-causes-error-message-from-debugger-terminated-due-to-signal-9)

Comment: @Malik I already read that, does not helped me.